# How do I combine two blocks?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a view of taxonomy categories.  I'm also using the built in search block, and the Bootstrap theme.

[image]

Is it possible to combine those blocks into one block?  I've tried creating a search view, but failed miserable.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking into this on the wrong way. You need a module to do this. It cannot be done by putting block in search.

You need to use one of these modules.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api
- https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search
- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete

Comment: And https://www.drupal.org/project/blockgroup if all what OP needs is one wrapper around multiple blocks.